# Add a POST parameter to fb:login button

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Hello im trying to set a POST when the user clicks the login with facebook button.. This is because in the code i made, if you are logged out, but loged in in facebook then you are automatically loged again in the site... so if you clic logout, you never logout..

To avoid this im trying to set a POST , to set a classic condition

```
 if ( isset ($_POST['fbconnect']))
```

I just need to add a hidden input and send that form usinf fb:login-button

here is what i have tried.. with no luck.

```
<form  name="fbconnect" method="post">
<input   type="hidden" name="fbconnect" value="fbconnect"  />

 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <fb:login-button scope='email,user_birthday'></fb:login-button></form>
 <?php
}
?>
 <script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
 appId : <?=YOUR_APP_ID?>,
 status : true,
 cookie : true,
 xfbml : true,
 oauth : true,
 });


FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
 // ------------------------------------------------------
 // This is the callback if everything is ok
  $(this).parents('form').submit();
 });
 };

(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
</script>
```

Also ive tried to replace `$(this).parents('form').submit();` form with the name of form, but it dosent work either

I Also tried this

```
<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
 appId : <?=YOUR_APP_ID?>,
 status : true,
 cookie : true,
 xfbml : true,
 oauth : true,
 });


FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
 // ------------------------------------------------------
 // This is the callback if everything is ok

 var url = "index.php";
var params = "fbconnect=fbconnect";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);


 });
 };

(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A better practice would be using a redirect when a user logs out, instead of a POST, i.e:

HTML:

```
<a onclick="FB.logout">Logout</a>
```

and Javascript:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
  if (response.status == "connected") {
    // log in login
  }
  else if (response.status != "connected") {
    // logout logic, i.e
    // location.href = "/sessions/logout";
    alert("User has disconnected")
    location.href = "/index.php?fbconnect=fbconnect"
  }
});
```

if you do insist of a post, you can use jQuery to simplfly things:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { 
  $.post("index.php", {fbconnect: fbconnect}, function(data, response) {
    alert(data);
  });

});
```

Comment: Sorry maybe your answer its great, but im really a noob on javascript, thats why i end up trying php solutions, Also iam implementing this in a code i cant touch the logout is set, and is based on cookies, and i just make a condition based on cookies to see if its logged in or not.... i will try both if you tell me how to use that script, or really is as easy as copy paste that?, thanks so much (im afraid messing with current logout, i cant mess with current logout)

Comment: With the second solution i got this Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ct1.addthis.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

Comment: Your first suggestion is working BUT PLS!! answer to this i just need to condition the status with my site, along with facebook status, response.status != "connected"... But im a fool in Javascript.. If i dont condition this produces a loop

Comment: @JulesMartinez I've updated the code, please check it out (no current_user_id)