# About FB.Event.subscribe and FB.login

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

first thanks for your time. Im trying to build a Event for facebook login button, to redirect to a PHP that always insert the user in db, if already exists just update some stuff..

The problem is this following this steps

1. My status is loged out from facebook & site.. i use facebook login button to login, it ask for my facebook credentials, if i login, it redirect me to index.php?fbconnect=fbconnect wich is great, and im Perfectly Logged In , in facebook & in my site!!
2. If i logout, everything its fine ....i am  just loged out from my site, not from facebook
3. If im connected to facebook , but not to my site, and click "login with facebook", NO redirection happends, so the user never logins, :( WHY?

I have tried this 3 different methods to redirect but all of them just work as i mention before.

This is a solution im trying to fix the issue i comment [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777760/add-a-post-parameter-to-fblogin-button) if i got this redirection everything would be perfect. but its a shame it only work the first time

```
   <script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
 appId : <?=YOUR_APP_ID?>,
 status : true,
 cookie : true,
 xfbml : true,
 oauth : true,
 });



FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
 // ------------------------------------------------------
 // This is the callback if everything is ok
 window.location.href = 'http://www.page.com.mx/index.php?fbconnect=fbconnect';

 });


 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.page.com.mx/index.php?fbconnect=fbconnect';
});

 FB.login(function(response) {window.location.href = 'http://www.page.com.mx/index.php?fbconnect=fbconnect';
              //...
           });
          };


(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that we have 3 possible status when asking the fb.getloginstatus (connected, not_authorized, not 'connected' nor 'not_authorized'), I tested this solution in my app only for the first and the third status, this because in my app, when I logout, I'm logged out from facebook to. Anyway I get all this stuff from the facebook documentation.
I don't know if I understand right but the events you are searching for, the one which is fired by the login, is: 'auth.login' it's all written in the [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).

So, if you want to redirect the user, just, and only after he is logged in, you should handle the things in this way:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',
    function(response) {
        alert('you just login, come with me');
        //redirect
    }
);
```

I put this code in this function `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {` , just before to handle `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {`  but probably it's better to handle the auth.authResponseChange before the auth.login.

for last I would like to add that there are also other ways to collect user data once for each session

Comment: Just for who read, the FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', it's used 'For example, suppose you want to record Likes in your database whenever a button is clicked' same documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/